# How to check value available or not in sql and php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Hi friends  i am new persion of PHP & CI, Here i have one array , in this array **studentAbsentId** is one more array.

> My Model

```
public function admin_absent_list($params)
    {

        foreach($params['studentAbsentId'] as $absentIds)
        {
            $atnEntry = array
            (
            "studentAbsentId" => $absentIds,
            "studentAbsentDate" =>$params['studentAbsentDate'],
            "schoolId" =>$params['schoolId'],
             "morning" => "1"

            );
            $this->db->insert("student_absent_list" , $atnEntry); 
        }  
         $return = array("status" => "Success" );
         echo json_encode($return); 
    }
```

> print_r($params);

```
 Array
(
    [studentAbsentId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [schoolId] => 2
    [studentAbsentDate] => 2017-04-19

)
```

Here **studentAbsentId** is array so i am using for each loop and insert into database,upto now it is working fine.

> My Table

```
id     morning    evening     studentAbsentId   studentAbsentDate   schoolId

1        1          0            1                 2017-04-19         2
2        1          0            2                 2017-04-19         2
```

> here after my question start,normally first time table is empty so how many studentAbsentId  is there bassed on that it will insert.

- Now second time i call the function admin_absent_list($params),please see below

> print_r($params);

```
 Array
(
    [studentAbsentId] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [schoolId] => 2
    [studentAbsentDate] => 2017-04-19

)
```

Now **studentAbsentId** 2 and 3. and date is same (studentAbsentDate).

---

Now what i want to do means . i have to write one if condition like studentAbsentId already available in this table, bassed on date (studentAbsentDate) .means i want update **evening 1**, suppose studentAbsentId  not available means i want insert into this datas.

> Expected results

```
id     morning    evening     studentAbsentId   studentAbsentDate   schoolId

1        1          0            1                 2017-04-19         2
2        1          1            2                 2017-04-19         2

3        0          1            3                 2017-04-19         2
```

Comment: if you write native SQL query, you can use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` construction, that would be triggered by trying to re-insert with the same `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Basic example using pdo

```
$checkuser = $_POST["username"];
    $dados = $conexao_pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?');
$dados->bindParam(1, $checkuser);
$dados->execute();
if ($dados->rowCount() > 0) {
  $linha = $dados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  echo "not found"; 

  }else{

     echo "ok";
  }
```

Comment: Mr @ Otávio Barreto, codeigniter And PHP 5.6, can you please update your code based on my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You must create a model of students table, and you need create this method:

```
public function is_registered($id) {
      $query = $this->db->get_where('students_table', array('id' => $id));
      return  ! empty($query->row_array())
}
```

into the function

```
foreach($params['studentAbsentId'] as $absentIds)
    {
        if ( ! $this->student_model->is_registered($absentIds)) {
            $atnEntry = array
            (
               "studentAbsentId" => $absentIds,
               "studentAbsentDate" =>$params['studentAbsentDate'],
               "schoolId" =>$params['schoolId'],
               "morning" => "1"

            );
            $this->db->insert("student_absent_list" , $atnEntry); 
        }
    }  
     $return = array("status" => "Success" );
     echo json_encode($return);
```